# what is the best way to if if else?

Tags: c#

I seem to have a problem with this. First if statement works and last one works. Else if does not work. how do I correct it?

```
if (pProp.Name == ("_ProjectName"))
{
    var value = pProp.get_Value().ToString();

    if (value.IndexOf("hayy", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\ngardner\Desktop\test.txt", true))
        {
            writer.Write("B");
            return;
        }
    }
    else
        if (value.IndexOf("incu", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\ngardner\Desktop\test.txt", true))
            {
                writer.Write("B");
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\ngardner\Desktop\test.txt", true))
            {
                writer.Write("M");
            }
        }
}
```

This is to clarify my attempt to code this.

I need to scan the "_ProjectName" field for two different character segment combination. if the field is Purchase then I would like the second search to be found true and write "B".

search for "Hayy", if found use write out "B" to a text file
search for "Purch", if found use write out "B" to a text file
If neither are found, write "M" to a text file

Comment: How exactly does it not work?

Comment: Please explain the problem more clearly.

Comment: The outer most else needs to encapsulate the lower if and else in curly braces. Also, i don't see any else if in there...

Comment: Best question title of the month. Really what the best way to if if else?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy.  I think we should re-title it *Best Way to if if else if else*

Answer (score 4):

Your indentation is obscuring what is going on here: the final `else` is actually part of the outermost `if` block.

Your `if else` separated by a line break is very obfuscating indeed!

Indent properly and these problems vanish!

Comment: Well, actually I think indentation is correct `if ... else (if ... else)` and last else goes to inner if. Also indentation does not matters in C#

Comment: Yes I'm unclear. Indeed indentation does not matter. But proper indentation helps you get your blocks correct.

Answer (score 4):

- Your .indexof operators need to compare against -1 instead of 0 (unless you *really* want to ignore index 0).
- You need to move your using statement to the outermost encompassing block.
- Consolidate or better yet, remove, your return statements
- Bracket your else block

Try this:

```
if (pProp.Name == "_ProjectName")
{
    var value = pProp.get_Value().ToString();
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\ngardner\Desktop\test.txt", true))
    {
        if (value.IndexOf("hayy", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
        {
            writer.Write("B");
        }
        else
        {
            if (value.IndexOf("incu", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
            {
                writer.Write("B");
            }
            else
            {
                writer.Write("M");
            }
        }
    }
    // return here if needed
}
```

Comment: +1 I think real issue is comparing index with zero. Bracketing else block does not change anything in this case. Also the best way (I think) will be creating method which determines what to write and returns `B` or `M` based on conditions

Comment: I apologize, this is entirely [my fault](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20688120/2). I answered the OP's previous question and had a typo in my answer :(

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, I think that now it will work.

```
if (pProp.Name == ("_ProjectName"))
{
   var value = pProp.get_Value().ToString();

   if (value.IndexOf("hayy", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
   {
       using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\ngardner\Desktop\test.txt", true))
       {
                writer.Write("B");
                return;
       }
    }
    else
    {
        if (value.IndexOf("incu", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\ngardner\Desktop\test.txt", true))
            {
                writer.Write("B");
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\ngardner\Desktop\test.txt", true))
            {
                writer.Write("M");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What you have missed was to open a bracket in the first else statement and then close it at the end.

Comment: How does this change the flow of the program?  Adding brackets is nice, but doesn't change the functionality, right?